# What ingredient, besides beans, creates a complete protein together with rice?

Tags: rice, budget-cooking

I want a cheap option for complete proteins, which includes rice. But I do not like beans.

Which other ingredients can I combine with rice in order to get a complete protein? I do eat meat, but I am looking for cheaper solutions.

Comment: Meat is a complete protein on its own.  The issues with 'complete proteins' tend to be for vegetarians who aren't eating meat.

Comment: Dear Steve, your question, as it was, did not fit our site well (as evidenced by a downvote, a flag, and two close votes). Instead of closing it, I decided to rewrite it, creating a version which we can answer. I am aware that it is very different from your original intent. But: we do not do dish or recipe suggestions, so I had to remove this requirement. Also, "tasty" is subjective, which is another close reason. I hope that the information you can get from the new version is better for you than a complete removal of the question.

Comment: @rumtscho I tried answering, but it still came out as a nutrition answer...  if it isn't that, its just a recipe request with a rather odd criterion.  I am not sure this one can be made on topic.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ Your current answer is indeed a consensus-dependent nutritional answer, which is relevant to the OP's problem, but *it is not an answer* to the question as written. You can say "lentils" and leave it at that, or don't give an answer at all.

Comment: How about rice-and-whatever-you-want, and have a glass of milk? Or a fried-rice approach featuring an egg, and then you can include randomly whatever else you want.

Answer (score 4):

Rice tends to be high in the sulfur-containing amino acids, cysteine and methionine, but low in lysine.  So want you need to complement the rice are foods high in lysine.  Remember that the average adult male only needs about 3g of lysine daily which is easily provided by 3-4oz (90-120g) of meat, eggs, dairy, or soy protein (tofu, tempeh, lufu, miso, etc).  Since you do eat meat, all you need to do to save money and still get a complete protein is to eat less.  If you need more bulk in your meals, include a variety of vegetables, or a salad topped with nuts or seeds.

People who eat meat and other animal products to meet their recommended protein intake don't need to worry about not getting enough of any individual amino acid. Even vegetarians usually don't have a problem with this as long as they eat a variety of different plant-based protein sources, since beans with grains, beans with nuts or seeds and grains with nuts or seeds are all combinations that provide enough of all of the essential amino acids.

Also, it is not necessary to take in the full complement of essential amino acids in one sitting, as long as you eat at least the minimum required amounts over a 24 hour period.

Answer (score 1):

There's a middle-eastern dish called Mejadra, which at its simplest is basically rice and lentils with some fried onions and seasoning.

You'll find plenty of recipes for it online.

Comment: Rice and lentils? Really? That's the one combo I tried to avoid after reading the question.

Comment: @Jolenealaska : but we were never told *why* he didn't like beans.  If it's a texture thing, lentils might be okay.

Comment: One of my favorites. Caramelize *plenty* of onions, add to boiled lentils and rice (boil separately), season with salt and cumin, and serve with sour cream.

Answer (score 0):

How about Dirty Rice? Google it for a lot of good recipes. Meat, veggies and starch in a one pot meal. Liver (yuck) is optional, keep looking if you don't like it either.